# variable as shell command

Tags: shell, variables, command

I am writing shell script that works with files. I need to find files and print them with some inportant informations for me. Thats no problem... But then I wanted to add some "features" and make it to work with arguments as well. One of the feature is ignoring some files that match patterm (like *.c - to ignore all c file). So I set variable and added string into it.

```
#!/bin/sh
command="grep -Ev \"$2\"" # in 2nd argument is pattern, that will be ignored
echo "find $PWD -type f | $command | wc -l" # printing command
file_num=$(find $path -type f | $command | wc -l) # saving number of files
echo "Number of files: $file_num"
```

But, command somehow ignor my variable and count all files. But when I put the same command into bash or shell, I get different number (the correct one) of files. I though, it could be just beacouse of bash, but on other machine, where is ksh, same problem and changing `#!/bin/sh` to `#!/bin/bash` did not help too.

Comment: See [this FAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Comment: what is the value of reg ?

Comment: @AliISSA There souhld be $command, sorry...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command line including the arguments is processed by the shell before it is executed. So, when you run script the command will be `grep -Ev "c"`and when you run single command `grep -Ev "c"` shell will interpreter this command as `grep -Ev c`.

You can use this command to check it: `echo grep -Ev "c"`. 
So, just remove quotes in $command and everything will be ok )

Answer (score 0):

You need only to modify command value :

```
command="grep -Ev "$1
```